# Unable to start R serve on Windows VSC

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have installed the following extensions to VSC running on Windows: R, R Debugger, and R Tools. Nevertheless, when R server tries to start, I get this error message: `Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called 'languageserver'`.

I haven't found how to get and install such package. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[languageserver](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver) is a regular R package. Install it from CRAN with `install.packages("languageserver")`, like with any other package.